canonical-livepatch status
friends, after I've restored my system with timeshift,
got problem with canonical-livepatch
MY OS:
OS: Xubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x86_64 
Host: Inspiron 7559 1.3.1 
Kernel: 5.15.0-46-generic 
Uptime: 5 mins 
Packages: 2716 (dpkg), 9 (flatpak), 18 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.1.16 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
Terminal: xfce4-terminal 
Terminal Font: DejaVu Sans Mono 11 
CPU: Intel i7-6700HQ (8) @ 3.500GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M 
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 530 
Memory: 1051MiB / 7814MiB  

Terminal:
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:~$ canonical-livepatch status
internal error, please report: running "canonical-livepatch" failed: cannot find installed snap "canonical-livepatch" at revision 286: missing file /snap/canonical-livepatch/286/meta/snap.yaml

Searched but didn't find any kind of solution to my problem. Any Help?
Thanks.

Have you simply tried reinstalling the snap?  sudo snap remove canonical-livepatch && sudo snap install canonical-livepatch?

Doesn't help,                                                                          error: cannot perform the following tasks:

Stop snap "canonical-livepatch" services (systemctl command [--no-reload enable snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service] failed with exit status 1: stderr:
Failed to enable unit: Unit file snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service does not exist.)
Remove data for snap "canonical-livepatch" (282) (failed to remove snap "canonical-livepatch" base directory: remove /home/user_one/snap/canonical-livepatch: directory not empty)

